# Ambari 1.6.1 hadoop port 8088 no website

Tags: networking, curl, hadoop, configuration, port

i have two question about Ambari 1.6.1

I followed the official installation of hortonworks:
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.6.1.0/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap1.html

1. First question is about two network cards and therefore two networks.

   To make it clear there are two networks.
   Network 192.168.1. X is for the cluster
   Network 10.1.1.X ist for the internetconnection
   Every Server has a connection to both networks.

   Visualization:
   Cluster -Network 192.168.1.X—- |eth1 Server 1 eth0|—–Network 10.1.1.X——————-internet Access

   The idea was to shutdown the 10.1.1.X network for all other servers, therefore it is not possible for other User to connect to a Server behind the Namenode (Server1)

   **Question:** Is there any restriction about the Services and the Server to be in one network?
2. Secound question is about port 8088

   There should be a webpage providing some information as we can see here:
   http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1-latest/bk_using-apache-hadoop/content/running_mapreduce_examples_on_yarn.html

   However, if i try '# curl 10.1.1.55:8088' there is no service. 
   'curl 192.168.1.55:8088' provide an empty page (nothing to see, not even ..)

netstat -tunalp | grep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:8141           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3439/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:19888          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2712/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:61616               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2471/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1468/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10033               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2712/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:8050           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3439/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8660                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1957/gmond
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1332/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1299/cupsd
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:8088           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3439/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3290/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2471/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:10200          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2221/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8664                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1976/gmond
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8440                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1468/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1454/postmaster
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11001             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3290/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:8025           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3439/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8441                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1468/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8666                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1938/gmond
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:8188           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2221/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:8030           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3439/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8670                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1379/python2.6
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:10020          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2712/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.55:50090          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3842/java
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1332/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::5432                     :::*                        LISTEN      1454/postmaster
```

Additional I tried to shutdown ipv6 adding the following lines into /etc/syscntl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then i tried
    #curl localhost:8088
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to ::1: Network is unreachable

**Question:** The problem to connect to port:8088 is a consequential error of the two network configuration?

Comment: Isn't it 8080? That's what works for me!

Answer (score 0):

1. I have never heard about such restrictions.
2. You can Access Ambari at port 8080 (I can see that this Port is listening on your server). If you haven't changed the login-information for Ambari yet, you can login with admin/admin. ([Ambari Ports](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.2/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/reference_chap2_7.html))